# Issue with menu bar: how to link a html file to other html files?

Tags: html, css, navbar

Right now, I have the nav menu bar html code on all my html files (home.html, about.html, contact.html), but I was wondering if there's a way to put the nav bar html code in another file (i.e. menubar.html) and just link that file to the html files that I want the nav bar to be in. This way, if I want to make changes to the bar, I would just need to change one file, and not every single file that contains the it. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: do you have any server side language, i.e. php? if not, you might be interested in `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no proper way of "including" in HTML as of now. You can use `<iframe src="navbar.html"></iframe>` and customize css to hide borders to make it look smoother. But understand that there are still two HTML documents loading.

However, [HTML imports](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#link-type-import) will be packed in **future** HTML updates using link like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
        <link rel="import" href="navbar.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>What is a body without a heart?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

However you **can do it using AJAX** as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#navbar").load("navbar.html");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: It is also **possible in serverside languages** like PHP:

Eg: `include('navbar.php');` on your `anypages.php`

Comment: Upvoting this for the fact that I didn't know this and that's rly an awesome feature! Also: I guess he could work with an `<iframe>` to get a bit of the same result.